# Running ip or ifconfig from inside an UDEV Rule

Tags: bash, ip, udev, ifconfig

I am trying to create an udev rule from which I would like to invoke ifconfig or ip to change ip addresses from a usb kernel network interface. To do this, I created:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/home/user/nw-setup.sh 2&>>/home/user/udev.log"
```

In the `nw-setup.sh` I simply have:

```
!/bin/bash
echo "nw-setup: Starting." > /dev/kmsg
/sbin/ifconfig usb0 172.16.248.12 2&>>/home/user/udev.log
/sbin/ip addr add 172.16.248.12/24 dev usb0
```

I can see from dmesg that each time I plug in the usb device, I can see the "nw-setup: Starting." message. Therefore, I am sure that udev rule works as I expected. However, ifconfig or ip commands does not work (The IP is not set for usb0). If I copy either of those commands and paste it to the console I can directly see that IP is configured for usb0.

Any help is greately appreciated regarding how to approach this problem I'm having.

**EDIT** When I log "ip link" from nw-setup.sh, I get usb0 interface ready:

```
10: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default q0
    link/ether 92:7b:39:b9:04:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: What is the output in the `/home/user/udev.log` when it fails?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately

Comment: @A.B I updated the question. I get the usb0 name ready with ip link.

Comment: ok, wasn't this. I'm out of idea...